# Someone Using / Showing my entire website in different domain using iframe. What to do for Redirect?

Tags: redirect, iframe, external

Some one Using / Showing my entire website in different domain using iframe? I want to redirect to my page when they loading their domain ? what to do ?

Comment: It's so unclear that I can't even edit it. Not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Add a small script to the `<head>` of your page to change `window.location.href` of the parent

```
<script>
if (window.parent != this) {    // in the global scope this === window. 
                                // if the window isn't the same as the parent
                                // change the parent's location to ours.

  window.parent.location.href = window.location.href;

}
</script>
```

This works in FF24 and Chrome 29. You'd have to do your own compatibility testing.

Comment: `window.top.location` instead of `window.parent.location` will work if there are framesets instead of iframes.

Comment: @Mike : Thank you this is useful than my complicated script..  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a header to your site so that it won't be loaded across domains.

Alternatively:

`<meta http-equiv="X-FRAME-OPTIONS" content="SAMEORIGIN" />`

This will allow iframing in the same domain, but refuse in different domain.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php session_start(); 
ob_start();
?>
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['redirect'])) : $_SESSION['redirect'] = 0; endif; ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
var referrer = document.referrer;
if(referrer==''){}
else{<?php 
$_SESSION['redirect']++; 
if($_SESSION['redirect'] ==1): ?>window.top.location.replace("http://domain.com");<?php endif; ?>}
</script>
```